# $j^2 = 1$, but $j \neq \pm 1$; what is $j$?

Tags: notation, terminology

I was watching a Numberphile video about the favorite number of some mathematicians, and at one point, the creator of MinutePhysics said the following -

> Similar to the way that $i$ is $\sqrt{-1}$, but what that actually
>   means is that $i^2$ is $-1$, $j^2$ is $+1$, but $j$ is not $1$.

Here's the video with him saying all this - http://youtu.be/ygqIfLHGTu4?t=5m35s

I've searched the internet for anything about j, but this video seems to be the only place where $j$ is mentioned.

Does $j$ exist? If so, can someone explain what $j$ is?

Or is this whole $j$ thing just a joke?

Comment: Yes, $j$ is a shorthand for "joke". Much like this comment is $j$! :-)

Comment: @Sim $(-1)^2=1$

Comment: @GitGud So $j$ doesn't represent anything else then? I did question if it was just equal to $-1$, but I thought there might be more to it.

Comment: In Electrical Engineering however, j is used instead of i. So j = $\sqrt{-1}$ as well (if you're an electrical engineer)..

Comment: @Sim It all depends on what setting you're in. If you're dealing with regular stuff, then yes, $j=1$. It's a consequence of the fact that the only roots of the polynomial $x^2-1\in \Bbb C[x\textbf{]}$ are $\pm 1$. $\textbf{Edit:}$ I didn't watch the video, though.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number

Comment: @Sim : I would never write $i = \sqrt{-1}$, because it suggests that $-1$ has a principal square root, (e.g. $\sqrt{4} = 2$, not $-2$), namely $i$, which is "better" than $-i$, and whether this is the case is far from clear (there is no continuous square root function on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @Stefan, then how would you define $i$? Isn't the positive value ($i$) the principal square root of $-1$? (with "principal" not meaning "better" IMHO, but simply the simplest - the positive, as the square root is a function and can't yield two values for the same $x$).

Comment: @JMCF125 : I would define $i$ as _a_ solution of $x^2 = 1$.  Then there is another solution, $-i$.  Writing things like $\sqrt{-1}$, $\sqrt{-4}$, etc., gets you into trouble because you can "prove" things like "$\sqrt{-1} \sqrt{-1} = 1$".  And $i$ is not "positive" any more than $-i$ is.

Comment: @StefanSmith, isn't $\sqrt{-1}$ the solution (it can't be "a" solution, it does make a difference)? «you can "prove" things like "$\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=1$"»: no, I could not, $\sqrt a \sqrt b=\sqrt{ab}$ only in the real numbers. You must have a principal root, $i$ is positive [WLOG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality). How would you even imagine a complex plane otherwise?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The number of the form $a+bj$ are *split-complex numbers*. The *j* is exactly like what is *i* for complexes to *split-complex numbers*, exept with the property $j^2=+1$.
Using a matrix interpretation with these numbers, we have,

$i=\;\; \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\ 
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$

$i^2 =\;\; \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0\\ 
0 & -1
\end{pmatrix} = -I$

$I^2 = \;\; \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}^2 = \;\; \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$
But also we have

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\ 
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}^2 = \;\; \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} = I$

and $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\ 
-1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$ is actually the definition of *j* as a matrix, so $j^2=I$ and $j≠\pm I$.
 This 
[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number) explains it pretty well.

Comment: How to prevent confusing with the 'j' in Quaternions? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion

Comment: Look to my updated answer using matrix definitions. A split complex is defined using 2x2 matrices whereas a quaternion is defined as a 4x4 matrix. Matrices are quite simple for not confusing them!

Comment: We can also define quaternions as $2\times 2$ matrices with (certain) complex entries.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Yes you're right, I should have _2x2 real matrices_. And we could also add the most important property : $j^2=1$ in slpix-complexes. But $j^2=-1$ in Quaternions.

Comment: Worse still, [split-quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-quaternion) have $j^2=1$.